# Get version information for C# application with InstallSheild LE installer

Tags: c#, versioning, installshield, installshield-le

I have a C# program that I want to deploy with InstallSheild LE. I know how to make a setup.exe file to install the application and I know how to create a new installer that can upgrade a current installation.

Currently, I have my application get its version number from the installation log. It checks its version number (which is initially and empty string). If the version number is a an empty string, the application goes to the %TEMP% directory and reads the newest installation LOG file looking for the line that states the installation was successful and the line with the version information. The version information is saved in the application settings and used to detect if upgrades are available. To detect an update, it compares its version number to the version number of the setup.exe in the update location (on a network drive).

This implementation works, however, there are a few aspects of this that worry me and i would like to know if there is a better way to tell the application what version it is and saving this information (preferably not in a file that can be deleted). Obviously, the information would need to be update-able and preserved between runs. Ideally, I would like to be able to internally set the version number in my C# application without having to make assumptions about files being created, or file locations, etc to get it.

Thoughts??

I appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: can't you set the version to your main application EXE/DLL and get it from there? Assuming you are versioning your application files with each new release, not just the installers.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way was to hardcode the version number in the application. I then would preform a check, during program execution, for the version of the installer in the update location on the network drive. If the version of the installer in the network drive was greater than the hardcoded version in the application, the program would download the new installer, execute it via another process, and close the application so that the necessary files could be updated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you pretty much have to hardcode something in addition to the update location. The question then becomes what's best to hardcode. Here are some ideas, assuming that your installation's `ProductVersion` property contains the version you need to compare:

- The version in question, per your answer
- The `ProductCode` of your installation
- A registry location (specific to major versions)
- The `UpgradeCode` of your installation series
- A registry location (independent of major versions)

Those, in order, are each less likely to change than the one before it, and it should be trivial to have the installer write its version into a chosen registry location (put `[ProductVersion]` in a registry key's value) so that's my recommendation. Then the only required update is to change `ProductVersion` when you update your installation.

There is one other approach that could work without any special a priori knowledge. I'll sketch it out in Win32 API because I'm not familiar enough with the DTF wrappers:

1. Use [MsiEnumComponents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370097.aspx) or [MsiEnumComponentsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407947.aspx) to look at all the installed components on the machine - this could take a while
2. Use [MsiEnumClients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370094.aspx) or [MsiEnumClientsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407946.aspx) to identify the product (or products) that installed each component
3. Use [MsiGetComponentPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370112.aspx) or [MsiGetComponentPathEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408006.aspx) on each product-component pair to identify whether that pair installed your exe file (the location from which you are currently running)
4. Use [MsiGetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130.aspx) or [MsiGetProductInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370131.aspx) to retrieve the `ProductVersion`; if there was more than one client, you'll have to decide how to handle it - perhaps by using the largest version

(If you hardcode the `UpgradeCode` you can use [MsiEnumRelatedProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370103.aspx) in place of steps 1-3; if you hardocde the `ProductCode` you can jump directly to step 4. Typically you only need to call the Ex variants if you need to search per-user installations.)